# Can we image the interior of the earth by shooting weakly interacting particles through it?

Tags: particle-physics, geophysics, particle-detectors, imaging

Could we image the various layers of the earth by shooting weakly interacting particles through it? Let's say we shot a very high amount of neutrinos in one side (say, the north pole) and then collected some of them again (say, at the south pole) on the other side.

Additionally, could we use particles that interact with greater or less frequency with the matter in order to map out regions of varying densities? I imagine we could place emitters at different locations to map fewer layers of the earth from an angle.

What are the practical or theoretical impediments to doing this?

Comment: See the "Ice Cube" project--an antarctic neutrino telescope.

Comment: https://www.universetoday.com/12099/seeing-inside-the-earth-with-neutrinos/

Comment: @G.Smith definitely not using solar neutrinos, since the 2 cores never line up.

Comment: Do you consider sound waves as weakly interacting?

Comment: @JonCuster Well, it's not technically a particle, but it counts! That would be more like an ultrasound, right?

Comment: Well, kind of. It is how the interior of the Earth is studied...